# Close file in C

Tags: c, linux, file, fclose

Under Linux I use this code to redirect stdout and stderr on a file, as shown in the code the file is opened using fopen(f) and is it closed using close(fd).

```
int         fd;
FILE        *f;   

f = fopen("test.txt", "rb+");

fd = fileno(f);
dup2(fd,STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(fd,STDERR_FILENO);
close(fd);
```

My question is whether the **close(fd)** statement closes all file descriptors, or is it necessary to use **fclose(f)** as well ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is to close the outermost level. Here the FILE object pointed to by `f` contains the `fd` file handle but also internal data like a possible buffer and various pointers to it.

When you use `close(fd)`, you free the kernel structures related to the file, but all the data structures provided by the standard library are not released. On the other hand, `fclose(f)` will internally close the `fd` file handle, but it will also release all the resources that were allocated by `fopen`.

TL/DR: if you use `fd= open(...);` to open a file, you should use `close(fd);` to close it, but if you use `f = fopen(...);`, then you should use `fclose(f);`.

Comment: Also, user code should not generally close the standard streams.

Comment: And if you obtained the file descriptor associated with the stream (with `fileno`) , should that be left alone?

Comment: @Haris: the way you get the file descriptor has no influence here. What matters is that closing a lower level object cannot release resources associated with a higher level one.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in the other answers, you should use `fclose(f);` instead of `close(fd);`.

> My question is whether the close(fd) statement closes all file descriptors [...]

No, it won't close all file descriptors. The file descriptors `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO` will still remain open and will now refer to the opened file `test.txt`. However, these file descriptors should probably not be closed, as it is good programming practice for `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO` to remain valid until the end of the program. They will be automatically closed by the kernel on process termination.

Answer (score 0):

C FILE* streams use buffered I/O internally. fclose() flushes this buffer and then closes the file descriptor at OS level. close()'ing a FILE* stream may not flush this internal buffer and you may lose data. So for C streams always use C fxxx() functions.